# Align figcaption to bottom of image in figure

Tags: html, css, layout

```
<figure>
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/x/x" alt="figure">
     <figcaption>Nam elementum non massa at mattis.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I'm creating a CSS file and want to place the figcaption with 100% width and a semi-transparent background-color on top of the image, but I want the bottom of the figcaption box and the bottom of the image to always be the same regardless of what image is used.

Comment: what is the trouble you are facing? http://jsfiddle.net/PegtH/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/herrshuster/F9q2f/ is what I have right now but it's hacked together with magic numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use absolute positioning on the figcaption element. Don't forget to set "position: relative" on the figure element, too. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/armordecai/xL1bk6k7/

```
figure {
     position: relative;
}
figure img {
    display: block;
}
figcaption {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can also use the Flexbox approach.

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #777;
  padding-right: 35px;
  /*adjust this to control how far it should be from egde*/
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a6/Apple_cake_with_vanilla_ice_cream_2.jpg/800px-Apple_cake_with_vanilla_ice_cream_2.jpg" alt="wikimedia-commons_apple-cake"> <br>
  <figcaption>
    Apple cake with vanilla ice cream
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer a more subtle caption try the [`mix-blend-mode`](https://devdocs.io/css/mix-blend-mode) CSS property:

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
}
figure figcaption {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 15px;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: smaller;
  mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img alt="figure" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1498084393753-b411b2d26b34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;h=180&w=540&amp;q=30">
  <figcaption>
    <b>Ottawa road in the evening.</b>
    Photo by Marc-Olivier Jodoin on Unsplash
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Combine with [`brightness()`](https://devdocs.io/css/filter-function/brightness) to increase text luminosity.